# Get follower AND following list instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

What will be the easiest way to get follower and following list for my own account?

One problem is that I can't use instagram API beacuse they allow use their followers api for non-business reasons

One solution that i found is "inspect element" at instagram website and check out the request to the server. It's working but the problem is the paggination , 10 followers only per request so its will take forever if u have many followers.

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you use the Instagram API?

Comment: how many followers do you have ?